# Monitor has duplicated refresh rate in the same resolution

Tags: ubuntu, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I'm dealing with interesting issue on Ubuntu with 2 connected monitors via HDMI.
One of them (HDMI2) has `60.00` **twice** for `1920x1080` resolution in xrandr output.
How it's even possible? Is there some way how to fix this issue? I believe that having same refresh rate for same resolution isn't OK.

It causes us problems with extending monitors and running Chrome on each screen independently while we need use FullHD resolution (1920*1080).
More exactly we call xrandr this way to join (extend) 2 screens:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0
```

With result like `1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    59.94`. But both web browsers (Chrome) are running on screen HDMI1 instead of on each screen independently. However, extending screens via Ubuntu's native monitors setting we get this xrandr output:
`1920x1080     60.00   60.00*    59.94`. In this case, web browsers can run on each screen independently. <- wanted behavior.
PS: In both cases we run second Chrome browser with `--window-position=1920,0` but in first case it seems this is fully ignored as Chrome is running on screen one (HDMI1).
Any ideas?

---

Output of `xrandr --verbose`:

```
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (0x1d0) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 610mm x 0mm
        Identifier: 0x43
        Timestamp:  16781814
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
        Brightness: 1.0
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       1
        CRTCs:      0 1 2
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff0021943b2a01010101
                1e130103a33d0078efee91a3544c9926
                0f5054000000d100a9c0d1c095008140
                81809040a940283c80a070b023403020
                3600d8870000001e000000fd0028550a
                6e15ff0a202020202020000000fc0057
                61766553686172650a202020000000ff
                00303130303932330a2020202020018e
                02031a74474c00000000000023090701
                8301000065030c001000283c80a070b0
                234030203600d8870000001e00000000
                00000000000000000000000000000000
                00000000000000000000000000000000
                00000000000000000000000000000000
                00000000000000000000000000000000
                00000000000000000000000000000094
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (8, 12)
        content type: No Data 
                supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
        aspect ratio: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1200 (0x47) 154.000MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1d0) 148.500MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x46) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1b5) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x1200 (0x1d1) 202.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  75.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x1d2) 189.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  87.50KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  70.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x1d3) 175.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  81.25KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  65.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x1bb) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1d4) 214.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1808 end 1984 total 2288 skew    0 clock  93.86KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1105           clock  84.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1d5) 187.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1800 end 1976 total 2272 skew    0 clock  82.31KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1099           clock  74.89Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1d6) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1400x1050 (0x1d7) 179.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1504 end 1656 total 1912 skew    0 clock  93.88KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1105           clock  84.96Hz
  1400x1050 (0x1d8) 156.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1504 end 1648 total 1896 skew    0 clock  82.28KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1099           clock  74.87Hz
  1400x1050 (0x1d9) 101.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  64.74KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1080           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x900 (0x1da) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1db) 157.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  91.15KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1072           clock  85.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1bc) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1bd) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x1dc) 157.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1544 end 1696 total 1952 skew    0 clock  80.43KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  948           clock  84.84Hz
  1440x900 (0x1dd) 136.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1536 end 1688 total 1936 skew    0 clock  70.64KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  942           clock  74.98Hz
  1440x900 (0x1de) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x960 (0x1df) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  85.94KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1011           clock  85.00Hz
  1280x960 (0x1e0) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1366x768 (0x1e1) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1366 start 1436 end 1579 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  774 total  798           clock  59.79Hz
  1360x768 (0x1e2) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1424 end 1536 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  795           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x800 (0x1e3) 122.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  71.55KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  843           clock  84.88Hz
  1280x800 (0x1e4) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  62.79KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  838           clock  74.93Hz
  1280x800 (0x1e5) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x1be) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x768 (0x1e6) 117.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  68.63KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  778 total  809           clock  84.84Hz
  1280x768 (0x1e7) 102.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  60.29KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  778 total  805           clock  74.89Hz
  1280x768 (0x1e8) 68.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  47.40KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  778 total  790           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x1bf) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x1e9) 94.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1168 total 1376 skew    0 clock  68.68KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  808           clock  85.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x1c2) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x1ea) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x1c3) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1eb) 56.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  896 total 1048 skew    0 clock  53.67KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  631           clock  85.06Hz
  800x600 (0x1ec) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x1c4) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1c5) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x1ed) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x1ee) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x1ef) 36.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  696 end  752 total  832 skew    0 clock  43.27KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  509           clock  85.01Hz
  640x480 (0x1cc) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x1f0) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x1ce) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x1f1) 35.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  756 end  828 total  936 skew    0 clock  37.93KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  446           clock  85.04Hz
  640x400 (0x1f2) 31.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  445           clock  85.08Hz
  640x350 (0x1f3) 31.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  350 start  382 end  385 total  445           clock  85.08Hz
```

Output of `sudo get-edid -b 1 -q|parse-edid`:

```
1
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "RTK FHD"
        ModelName "RTK FHD"
        VendorName "RTK"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 23 of 2011
        # EDID version 1.3
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 520 320
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "true"
        Horizsync 30-81
        VertRefresh 56-76
        # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz

        #Extension block found. Parsing...
        Modeline        "Mode 17" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 1" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 2" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 5" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 6" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 7" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 8" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 9" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 10" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 11" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 12" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 13" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 14" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 15" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 16" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 18" 74.25 1920 2008 2052 2200 540 542 547 562 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 19" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 20" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
        Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 17"
EndSection
```

Comment: What issue? The monitor is simply exposing it's different capabilities via EDID. That by itself is not a problem, but a useful feature. It seems that your problem is with your display configuration, but since you do not elaborate on the symptoms, it is impossible to find a root cause. Please do not create a [x-y-problem](https://xyproblem.info/), but edit your question with a description of the issue you are facing.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Edited ;)